# Google Cloud Endpoints: Websockets and JWT

Tags: nginx, websocket, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been developing a mobile app (iOS) with gRPC via Firebase auth(z). My server is using GKE with the NGinx proxy - so now I'm developing the Web UI for the deeper configuration of a user account. I prefer not to fall back to REST API's, so I was wondering if Google Cloud Endpoints supports websockets, and would it also prevent non-authorised app users from trying to make a request? With websockets I know it's possible, but as I'm tied in with gRPC with Cloud Endpoints, I'm just checking before I fall back to REST API calls (I prefer not to!).

Summary: Does Google Cloud Endpoints support Websockets with JWT auth tokens from Firebase?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Cloud Endpoints doesn't support WebSockets at all.

Btw, what is your use case for WebSockets? WebSocket won't work with gRPC either. If you just want to talk to your gRPC service from Web UI, [transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/transcoding) should work. It works with JWT from Firebase auth.

Comment: Transcoding is most likely the option I'll go with. I was trying to avoid REST API's as I find them painful now that we have things like RxJS.

Comment: I ended up using websockets after all, but only for app live notifications. I used the google cloud load balancer and validated my own JWT token from Firebase. Using pubsub I have a cluster of websocket GKE containers to handle larger loads - pubsub doing the heavy lifting for session specific messages

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like ESP supports websockets now](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/start_esp/start_esp.py#L535), using the `"--enable_websocket"` flag in the esp config.

Comment: The docs say that while the `--enable_websocket` flag is now deprecated, websockets should be enabled by default: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/migrate-to-esp-v2#deprecated-flags. However it seems that ESPv2 has an issue with closing the WS connection after 15s: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/704

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Endpoints ESP doesn't support websockets.

However, Google Cloud Endpoints have open sourced their [Extensible Service Proxy](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) implementation. Internally it's implemented as a [custom nginx module](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/src/nginx/config.cc#L278). Since Nginx supports websockets, it should be feasible to add support to their nginx:esp module.

But it's definitely out of scope for me. :-)